# Maven won't run tests from parent or child projects

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit

I got a multi-module project. Each project has its own unittest same for the parent project. When I use mvn test no tests are run and the target folder does not contain any test classes. Parent project doesn't even create a target folder

Structure looks like this:

```
|-module1-> pom.xml
|-module2-> pom.xml
|-module3-> pom.xml
|-src/main
|-src/test/java/MyTest.java
|-pom.xml
```

See poms below ( I omited standard pom boilerplate)

parent pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.tests</groupId>
<artifactId>unit-tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Child pom has:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>unit-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Whenever i run `mvn clean test` no tests are run and in the console i get something like:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building unit-tests 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Btw, parent project does not have any source code, just tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using packaging `pom`. With that kind of packaging you're only allowed to run a small number of goals bound to phases (like `install` and `deploy`). In order to run the tests in the parent you must be explicit about your intentions, like this:

```
$mvn clean compiler:testCompile surefire:test

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.tests.unit_tests.TestModules
Test1!
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.tests.unit_tests.TestModules
[ERROR] test1(com.tests.unit_tests.TestModules)  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.tests.unit_tests.TestModules.test1(TestModules.java:11)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   TestModules.test1:11
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] unit-tests ......................................... FAILURE [  1.262 s]
[INFO] module1 ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.473 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-02T11:04:50-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/207M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That way you are telling `maven` that you want to compile (generate your target) and run your tests in the aggregator (which has the parent pom). Otherwise `maven` will only run the tests in the modules.

```
$mvn test

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] unit-tests
[INFO] module1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building unit-tests 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building module1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ module1 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ module1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ module1 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ module1 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ module1 ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] unit-tests ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] module1 ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.424 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.504 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-02T11:06:24-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/241M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know that it is a hard reading, but you should check it out: 
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Packaging

> For example, a project that is purely metadata (packaging value is
>   pom) only binds goals to the install and deploy phases (for a complete
>   list of goal-to-build-phase bindings of some of the packaging types,
>   refer to the [Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)).

**EDIT**

As eis pointed out. Even though it's possible to do it, maven made it hard to do it because you **SHOULDN't** do it by default. Your unit tests should be in the module they are testing. It's not a good practice to scatter them.

> The answer is: you can do it, yes. But you shouldn't! There are somethings in life that you can do, but shouldn't...

If we were talking about `integration tests` that would be a different story.. That's a different discussion.

Cheers!

Comment: while this is correct, a pom packaged module *should not* contain tests by definition. I think you're doing a disservice in advising how to run tests in a module that should not contain them in the first place - it will only lead to trouble in the long run.

Comment: @eis I agree with, but it's possible to execute them. Even though not desirable. I totally agree with you. Unit tests should be in the module they are testing.

Comment: @eis I'm answering the question, because you can do it. But I'll edit it and say explicitly that it isn't a good practice. Cheers!

Comment: @wleao, I moved my tests to a child module. when i call mvn clean test -pl :module1. I get "No tests to run."

Comment: @testing_kate Are you using the org.junit.Test annotation in your tests? Show some code in your question.

Comment: @wleao, the issue with tests not running in child modules was fixed after i changed junit dependency version to 4.12 instead default 'release' generated by intellij. Although i have no idea why

Answer (score 2):

The maven surefire plugin runs all JUnit Test where the name of the testclass ends with *Test* - with a capital 'T'. According to your info your test class is named `Mytest`. Refactor that class to be named `MyTest` will make it work.

Comment: It was a typo in the question, in the code naming convention is followed

Answer (score 0):

multimodule parent has the packaging `pom`, and as such, can by definition only contain the pom, not any source code (not even test source code!). This is the reason your tests won't run and you don't get a target folder: there cannot be anything to run or compile on a project of type pom. A multimodule parent is only meant to group the modules together.

Comment: that doesn't answer why tests from child projects are not being run

Comment: that doesn't cut it. Check my answer, it will be helpful.

Comment: @testing_kate correct, it doesn't. If that was the point of this question, you should edit accordingly, removing any misleading information about tests in the pom project (and I will delete this answer then). It definitely should.